# Is there a way to view/edit search terms associated with a concept within the IBM Watson Insights for Medical Literature COVID-19 Navigator?

Tags: ibm-watson

When I select a concept like "antibodies" to build my corpus query within the navigator, is there a way I can see which specific search terms are included?

Is there a way to edit the specific terms associated with a given concept?

Concept search is great, but I need a way to validate the terms employed and possibly tailor them if necessary to find the right content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Navigator tool](https://covid-19-navigator.mybluemix.net/#), the concepts available in the Concepts tab are based on the UMLS dictionary/ontology from the National Center for Biotechnology Information ([NCBI](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/index.html)). In the UMLS dictionary, the concept “antibodies” includes 26 terms (or surface forms) including “antibodies, antibody, anti-body, unidentified antibody, unidentified ab, etc.”. Each UMLS concept on average contains about 5 terms.

In addition, many UMLS concepts have parent/child/sibling relationships with other UMLS concepts allowing you to expand your search to those concepts and all of their terms. If you click on the white search card for the “antibodies” concept, you will see a set of checkboxes allowing you to include those related terms in your search. By default, the “Include children” checkbox is checked meaning all the concepts with a “child” relationship to the selected concept are included. For “antibodies” there are over 1000 child concepts which translates to over 5000 search terms including specific antibodies like “omalizumab, avelumab, antivenin, Immunoglobulin G, aspergillus Igm, etc.”.

You’ll also notice a checkbox for “Include MeSH concepts”. This is another way to expand your search. MeSH stands for [Medical Subject Headings](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh) from the National Center for Biotechnology Information (NCBI). MeSH is another dictionary/ontology that applies to the Medline and PubMed documents in the COVID-19 corpus. Checking this box for “antibodies” will include those terms and their children along with the UMLS-based terms.